# Using two different mac protocols at the same time in NS-2

Tags: tcl, protocols, ns2

I have a problem for using two different mac protocol at the same time. Assume I use these 2 macs briefly like this :

```
set opt(mac_11n)            Mac/802_11n
set opt(mac_11bg)           Mac/802_11

$ns node-config -macType $opt(mac_11n) 

for {set i 0} {$i < 3 } {incr i} {
   set node($i) [$ns node 1.0.$i]
}

$ns node-config -macType $opt(mac_11bg)

for {set i 3} {$i < 6 } {incr i} {
   set node($i) [$ns node 1.0.$i]
}
```

Assume that other configurations are like typical NS-2 TCL file. But when I run the application, only the first configuration has throughput (in this case mac_11n) but the latter one has no throughput at all. Then when I switch the position (configure mac_11bg first), only mac_11bg has throughput. Can I use these two different mac protocols at the same time like this? and how to solve this problem? because I need to use both of them simultaneously

Comment: What are the configurations of the nodes after that code has run?

Answer (score 1):

I think You cannot run two mac layer simultaneously. You have to create gateway nodes then you can transfer data from one node (mac_11n) to another(802_11) using gateway nodes.